# Magento2 Admin Side Custom configuration page with a menu

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, custom-menu

I created an admin menu in magento2 which is linked to a new admin page. I would like to have my own configuration fields (some text fields) in this new page with a save button.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module create system.xml file on follwing path
/app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml and add following code

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="tops" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Delivery Message</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="cod" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Delivery message</label>
            <tab>tops</tab>
            <resource>Namespace_Module::cod_config</resource>
            <group id="catalog" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="codenable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Display Text</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Text for delivery message</label>
                    <comment>This text will display on the product detail page under addto cart button.</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
        <section id="category_slider" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Category Slider</label>
            <tab>tops</tab>
            <resource>Namespace_Module::cod_config</resource>
            <group id="catalog_category" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="category_id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Please enter category ids comma saperated.</label>
                    <comment>Only first 2 ids data will display on home page.</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Now go to Stoere->Configuration you will get your section called Delivery Message

Comment: I created a new menu like 'Store' and created a page with link.How can I add the above mentioned code under that menu link opening page?

Comment: You need this section in configuration area or your custom page ?

Comment: yes.Custom page with a menu option

Comment: I create a menu which is linked to a new admin page. I would like to have my own configuration fields in this new page with a save button

Comment: In that case you need to create model, and table for save your data.

Comment: Can you explain with a simple example?

Comment: Check this link https://webkul.com/blog/create-grid-edit-add-grid-row-and-installer-in-magento2/
At the end of explanation you can find download link